# How to hide select a spec in swagger-ui.html

Tags: swagger, springfox

How to hide select a spec in swagger-ui.html
Development environment: springboot+swagger2.9.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To be able to customize parts of the Swagger UI provided by Springfox you have to provide your own version of a JS, HTML or CSS file. In your case, only a custom CSS file is needed.

Put a CSS file (e.g. `springfox.css`) in the resources folder. The content of the CSS file should be:

```
.select-label {
    display: none !important;
}
```

`select-label` is class name of "Select a spec" label area.

Now you have to make your CSS file accessible for Springfox. Therefore, create a simple `Controller` that provides your CSS file as a `Resource` at `/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.css` path.

```
@Controller
@Log4j2
public class CustomizedSwaggerUI {

    @Value("classpath:springfox.css")
    private Resource cssFile;

    @ApiIgnore
    @GetMapping(value = "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.css")
    public void resourceCSS(HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.setHeader("content-type", "text/css;charset=UTF-8");
            byte[] file = IOUtils.toByteArray(Objects.requireNonNull(cssFile.getURI()));
            response.getOutputStream().write(file);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Error loading customized springfox css file.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
I solved it using custom swagger html, css, js.